# Can you send a message to a websocket client from a non-websocket lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I have a nodejs websocket AWS lambda endpoint (Api Gateway) set up and it connects and can echo messages back. During initial connection, I save the endpoint and connection_id to a database. That gets saved just fine. If I open a browser client, and connect to the websocket endpoint, I can connect successfully, and send a message from the browser successfully - I have code to echo the message back, and it works.

Now, in another nodejs lambda, one that provides a REST endpoint, I have code that loads the connection_id from the database and does this:

```
// 'connection' is loaded successfully from DB (I log it and see the right values)
let api = new AWSSDK.ApiGatewayManagementApi({apiVersion: '2018-11-29', endpoint: connection.endpoint});

await api.postToConnection({
                ConnectionId: connection.connection_id,
                Data: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello World' })
            }).promise();
```

However, the code in the REST endpoint (code above) always gets a 410 error in the postToConnection. I know the connection is still active, since I can connect to it and ping it in a browser client just prior to testing the REST API above.

Is it not possible to post to a websocket connection from a non-websocket lambda?

Comment: Please check whether this AWS lambda has enough permission to access API gateway and send messages into the socket.

Comment: I added something like this, and don't get any permissions error:

    - Effect: Allow
          Action: 
            - execute-api:ManageConnections
            - execute-api:Invoke
          Resource:
            #- "arn:aws:execute-api:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:<id>/*/*/@connections/{connectionId}"
            - "arn:aws:execute-api:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:*"

Comment: In order to send message to a socket you need to establish the connect first. Without that you cannot send message. That is how that protocol works. Only that client and server can send messages over that socket connection. In your case, you might have to check the pub sub architect and implementation.

Comment: This is in a lambda, and they are ephemeral, it's the API Gateway that maintains the connection with the client.  That's why you get the connection id to post to.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use this to send messages from the backend to your clients.

To send a callback message to the client, use:

> POST
>   https://{api-id}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{stage}/@connections/{connection_id}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html